# User specified non-type template parameter dependent on deduced template

Tags: templates, enums, c++14, template-argument-deduction, non-type

I have an array-like class with non-type `enum` accessors.

```cpp
template <class T, class Enum, size_t N>
struct enum_array {
    template <Enum E>
    void do_fancy_thing_with_non_type();
};
```

I am having issues implementing a get function (it is in a seperate namespace) since the provided non-type template parameter depends on the deduced class template parameters.

```cpp
// This cannot work, 'Enum' isn't deduced at point of declaration.
template <Enum E, class T, class Enum, size_t N>
constexpr T& get(enum_array<T, Enum, N>& a) noexcept {
    //return ...;
}

get<some_enum::val>(arr);
```

I understand c++17 has `auto` template parameters which would solve this issue, but unfortunately this code is c++14 only. Is there a way to deduce a non-type parameter type while still requiring it be provided by the user in c++14?

Comment: Probably not possible. You could do something like `from(arr).get<some_enum::val>();` or make the get a member-function.

Comment: Do you use legacy `enum` or scoped `enum class`? If you use the former, then an easy fix, would be to replace `Enum e` by something like `int e` instead. Otherwise, I don't see how you could do it and still be `constexpr`.

Comment: @Phil1970 Unfortunately they are scoped. Oh well, a member function it'll have to be. thx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this isn't possible in c++14. The best solution is to use a member function.